# Does SES free tier extend to AWS Fargate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, aws-fargate

Amazon SES offers a free tier that is eligible for applications running on EC2 instaces or in Elastic Beanstalk containers. However, am I also eligible for the free tier if I am using AWS Fargate?

As far as I understand, *formally* Fargate is neither EC2 nor Beanstalk, so the rules written in the official AWS documentation do not apply :( but I might be missing something as a novice AWS user.

Answer (score 2):

I think Fargate is included in SES.  I can find no direct reference but several indirect references so your mileage may vary.  Here's my logic:

**What is Fargate**

> AWS Fargate is a serverless compute engine for containers that works with both Amazon Elastic Container Service (ECS) and Amazon Elastic Kubernetes Service (EKS).

**What is ECS**

> Amazon Elastic Container Service (ECS) is a highly scalable, high performance container management service that supports Docker containers and allows you to easily run applications on a managed cluster of Amazon EC2 instances.

**What is EKS**

> Kubernetes groups containers into logical groupings for management and discoverability, then launches them onto clusters of EC2 instances.

From the references above Fargate utilizes ECS or EKS.  ECS and EKS are both clusters of EC2 instances.

As you pointed out, SES for EC2 users has a free tier.

[image]

Bottom line: by inference Fargate is basically clusters of EC2 instances which are a requirement for the SES free tier.

**References**
[Fargate FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/faqs/)
[ECS FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/faqs/)
[EKS FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/eks/faqs/)
[SES Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/the-amazon-ses-free-tier/)

Comment: This isn't correct at all. Fargate is not related to EC2 or SES in any way. SES is a service that can be used via the AWS APIs to send emails, and the free tier of SES allows 2,000 free emails per day. Fargate is also not related to Elastic Beanstalk. Fargate is an entirely separate service within ECS, and no free tiers currently apply to it as far as I can tell. If you want to use ECS with the free tier, you must use a qualifying EC2 instance.